# I can't implement pagination in Isotope js

Tags: javascript, php, pagination, jquery-isotope

I would like to implement pagination in isotope JS, I tried this :

In this code it work but I can't have few images per page...
I was following this tutorial https://tannermoushey.com/2012/12/isotope-paging/
I'm using Wordpress and ACF that why I have to call my images like this.

```
<?php

$page_num = 1; // starting page number
$items_per_page = 1; // how many posts per page?


echo '<section id="pins" class="content-posts isotope">';
$images = get_field('galerie');
foreach ($images as $i => $image):;

    $class = '';
    $classSize = '';
    if ($i % 2) {
        $class = 'grid-item--height';
        $classSize = 'gallery-height-1';
    } elseif ($i % 3) {
        $class = 'grid-item--height2';
        $classSize = 'gallery-height-2';
    } else {
        $class = 'grid-item--height3';
        $classSize = 'gallery-height-3';
    }




    //next page
    echo '<article class="goto-page next post isotope-item" page="' . ($page_num - 1) . '">' . //show on previous page
        '<a href="#" class="page" page="article.post[page~=' . ($page_num) . ']">' . //point to this page
        '<span>Next page</span></a>' .
        '<div class="grid-item ' . $class . '">
                  <img src="' . $image['sizes'][$classSize] . ' " alt=" ' . $image['alt'] . '"">
              </div>' .
        '</article>';


    //previous page
    echo '<article class="goto-page previous post isotope-item" page="' . $page_num . '">' . //show on previous page
        '<a href="#" class="page" page="article.post[page~=' . ($page_num - 1) . ']">' . //point to this page
        '<span>Previous pages</span></a></article>';

    $page_num++; // increase the page number
    $i++;



endforeach;



echo '</section>';

?>
```

And here my jquery isotope from the tutorial

```
$('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: 100,
        gutter: 20,
        isFitWidth: true
    }
});


(function ($) {
    var container = $('section.content-posts');

    container.isotope( { itemSelector : 'article.post' } ); // specify container

    container.isotope( { filter : "article.post[page~='1']" } ); // starting filter

    $('article.goto-page a').click(function(){
        var selector = $(this).attr('page'); // make selector equal to the value we put in 'page'

        container.isotope( { filter : selector });
        return false;
    })
} )(jQuery);
```